# How to include noise in clustering evaluation?

Tags: clustering, metric, noise

When evaluating clustering methods which do have a definition for noise points (like dbscan), how noise will affect evaluation?

Consider a clean dataset like well known Iris dataset. There is no noise in it. In evaluation metrics like homogeneity should we remove noise labels and then compute the metric?

Ex:

```
True_labels = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]
Expected_labels = [a, a, -1, b, -1]
```

Do we need to alter these labels some how like this?

```
True_labels = [1, 1, 2]
Expected_labels = [a, a, b]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple choices. For example, you could treat all noise as a single cluster, or each object as being its own 1-element cluster.

I don't think any of the evaluation methods works very well in these cases though.
Evaluation of clusterings is pretty much broken by *design*, unfortunately.

Comment: Clustering illness define and evaluation is breaking my bones at the moment!

Comment: Try a problem-driven approach. Don't solve math, solve real data problems; don't cluster random data, but try to solve some real world problem.

Comment: Can we set a time to chat about this?

Comment: I can't help you that much - I don't have a code or formula solution; but the idea is to continue as if your clustering result was good, and then look back after the next step, if you need to go back and retry.

Comment: I don't meant to ask for formula or code. I most want to know about the way I need to do the whole thing.

Comment: what do you plan to do next with the clustering result?

Comment: I'm going to develop a density based clustering algorithm to cluster network traffic in huge amounts (aka big data). But I'm stocked now.

Comment: But what do you do **when** you have found a cluster? You'll never know if a cluster is good when you stop after clustering.

Comment: What people do normally in such situation? Maybe validate clustering result via some metric.

Comment: Assume your validation was good for now. What do you plan to do next? How do you **use** the result?

Comment: Actually using the result is not part of my thesis, but one can assign labels to it via some samples of each cluster. Applications could be normal/abnormal packets for future ids or application detection or sth like that.

Comment: But it could as well be just one cluster per client IP, then you did not gain anything. I haven't seen any convincing mining on IP data yet... **you'll have to *try* this "sth like that" part**, to see if your clustering helps.

Comment: It much depends on data features.

Comment: So does the evaluation. Abstract evaluation is useless. You need to evaluate within the end user application, on real data, not at the clustering level in a math domain.